# How do I create a zip file one folder up from the present working directory with NIO?

Tags: java, zip, uri, nio

I'm having trouble using the URI class.

I can create a zip file in c:\ with code like this:

```
// Properties for archive file we're creating
Map<String, String> archiveProperties = new HashMap<>(); 
archiveProperties.put("create", "true");
archiveProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");        
URI archiveLocation = URI.create("jar:file:/" + "my.zip");

// Create archive
FileSystem archive = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archiveLocation, archiveProperties);
```

But I really want the zip file to be created one directory up, if you will, from the present working directory.  I've tried a lot of things, including:

```
// Properties for archive file we're creating
Map<String, String> archiveProperties = new HashMap<>(); 
archiveProperties.put("create", "true");
archiveProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");        
URI archiveLocation = URI.create("jar:file:../" + "my.zip");

// Create archive
FileSystem archive = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archiveLocation, archiveProperties);
```

But I either get an exception, URI is not hierarchical in this case, or it continues to be created in c:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution, albeit not very pretty:

```
// Properties for archive file we're creating
Map<String, String> archiveProperties = new HashMap<>(); 
archiveProperties.put("create", "true");
archiveProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");        

String filePathName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + FILE_SEPARATOR + ".." + FILE_SEPARATOR + "myfile.zip";
filePathName = filePathName.replace('\\','/');
filePathName = filePathName.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
URI archiveLocation = URI.create("jar:file:///" + filePathName);

// Create archive
FileSystem archive = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archiveLocation, archiveProperties);
```

Note FILE_SEPARATOR came from System.getProperty(file.separator)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix will be to use this

```
URI archiveLocation = URI.create("jar:file:///"+new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"/../my.zip");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it and got an exception.  :-(

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 14: jar:file:///C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\Eclipse workspace RTC Dev Stream2\bin\./../my.zip
 at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:870)

Comment: You just had to change the file separator to match your Windows environment like you did in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Naga.  I couldn't believe how difficult this seemingly easy task was to get working.